# Prove that $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$ $> 1$.

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$ $> 1$. I need to admit that I'm completely new to proof writing and I have completely no experience in answering that kind of questions. However, I came up with this:

Since $\sqrt{4}=2$ and $\sqrt{9}=3$ we have a following inequality: $2 < \sqrt{6} < 3$.

On the other hand we have $\sqrt{1}=1$ and $\sqrt{4}=2$ so we have $1 < \sqrt{2} < 2$.

Let $n = \sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$,

Therefore $ 1<n<3$, which implies that $n>1$.

Is this a correct proof?

Thank you.

Comment: No very, based on the inequalities you have established, you can only conclude that $0 < \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} < 2$. Notice that subtract two inequalities is different from adding them.

Comment: $\sqrt 6>\sqrt 2+1\Rightarrow 6>3+2\sqrt 2$ If you want you find $3+2\sqrt 2\approx 5.82$ or taking again the square you get $9>8$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, your proof is not correct. The bound $\sqrt{6} > 2$ combined with the bound $\sqrt{2} < 2$ is too weak - consider $2.1 > 2$ and $1.9 < 2$, while their difference is far less than $1$. In fact, the best this can imply is that $\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} > 0$.

---

For a different approach, notice that your inequality is equivalent to

$$\sqrt{6} > 1 + \sqrt{2}$$

Square both sides and see what happens.

Comment: At the end we have: $9>8$. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Yes, the inequality is equivalent to $9 > 8$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2} = \frac{6-2}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}= \frac{2}{\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}}> \frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{6+2}{2}}}=1$$

$\bf{Added:}$

$$\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} > \sqrt{6.25} - \sqrt{2.25} = 2.5 - 1.5 = 1$$
since the function $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is concave.

Comment: RMS-AM inequality to the rescue!

Comment: @boojum:  Also does $\sqrt{x^2 + x} -\sqrt{x^2 - x}> 1$   :-)

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sqrt 6-\sqrt 2>1$ if and only if $\sqrt 6>1+\sqrt 2.$ The square on right-hand side of the inequality is $1+2+2\sqrt 2=3+2\sqrt 2$. The remaining question is now whether $3\geq 2\sqrt 2$. Again by squaring this is equivalent to $9\geq 8$ which is valid.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$ is positive because $\sqrt{x}$ is minimal at $0$ and always increasing at $x>0$.

Because $x^2$ is $1$ at $x=1$ and always increasing at $x>0$, numbers greater than 1 remain greater than $1$ when squared and $8-\sqrt{48}$ results from squaring $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}\,$.

Since $8-\sqrt{49}=1$ and $\sqrt{49}$ exceeds $\sqrt{48}$ given properties of $\sqrt{x}$, it then follows that $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2} > 1$.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It's not explained as clear as it can be, but it's saying $1= 8 -\sqrt{49} < 8 - \sqrt{48} $ and then its square rooting the inequality to obtain $1 < \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Square rooting did not occur. The inequality $√6-√2 > 1$ isn't obtained.  Rather, the LHS is proven greater than 1 first by proving the LHS is positive, then by proving how the LHS remains greater than 1 when squared and why that's true in general.

Comment: @DionelJaime Thanks for using better mathjax in your comment. Have edited Tim's answer accordingly. Will retract the downvote. Tim ! Please click on 'edited ... ago ' to see what exactly you should have done.

Comment: Thanks @Kurt G.

Comment: $(\sqrt{2}+1)^2=3+2\sqrt{2}\lt 3+3\frac{3}{2}=6\implies\sqrt{2}+1\lt\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Why don't we find out what needs to be true for the inequality to hold? If we end up some place we know is true, then all we need to do is start at the bottom and work backwards. So let's assume it's true and see what happens. 
$$\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} > 1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \left(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2} \right)^2 > 1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 6 - 2\sqrt{12} + 2 > 1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 7 - 4\sqrt{3} > 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 7 > 4\sqrt{3}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{7}{4} > \sqrt{3}$$

Is this last line true? Well, of course. $\frac{7}{4} = 1.75$ and $\sqrt{3} = 1.73\cdots < 1.75$. 
Now, just start at the bottom (which we know is a true fact) and work your way up to end up at the inequality the question asks you to prove.

Comment: Going by your method, $\sqrt6-\sqrt2$ = 2.44-1.41 = 1.03>1, hence proved.

Comment: @Nikunj I think it's not the same case. Because you're approximating two numbers at a time.

Comment: I would've stopped at $7 > 4\sqrt{3}$ and then put the $4$ inside the square root to obtain $\sqrt{49} > \sqrt{48}$. Then there's nothing to debate.